Getting generic class assigned to given object type
I'm writing a C# program that calculates total worth of financial assets.
Each asset is represented by asset ID. There are calculator classes specialized for calculating worth of specific asset ID.
public interface IAssetId
{
    string GetSymbol();
}

public class Currency(string currency) : IAssetId
{
    public string GetSymbol() => currency;
}

public class EtfTicker(string ticker) : IAssetId
{
    public string GetSymbol() => ticker;
}

public interface IAssetWorthCalculator<in TAssetId> where TAssetId : IAssetId 
{
    decimal CalculateWorth(TAssetId assetId);
}

public class MoneyWorthCalculator : IAssetWorthCalculator<Currency>
{
    public decimal CalculateWorth(Currency assetId) ...
}

public class EtfWorthCalculator : IAssetWorthCalculator<EtfTicker>
{
    public decimal CalculateWorth(EtfTicker assetId) ...
}

Now let's say I have a list of different asset IDs for which I want to calculate total worth.
List<IAssetId> assetIds = [
    new Currency("USD"),
    new EtfTicker("SPY")
];

decimal worth = TotalWorthCalculator.GetTotalWorth(assetIds);

The total worth calculations would be performed in a class that would look something like this:
public class TotalWorthCalculator
{
    public decimal GetTotalWorth(IList<IAssetId> assetIds)
    {
        decimal sum = 0;
        foreach (IAssetId id in assetIds)
        {
            IAssetWorthCalculator<IAssetId> worthCalculator = ???
            decimal worth = worthCalculator.CalculateWorth(id);
            sum += worth;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}

I'm trying to figure out a way to implement a class, that returns a proper worth calculator for given asset ID e.g.

if the asset ID is currency, then the class returns MoneyWorthCalculator object
if the asset ID is ETF, then it returns EtfWorthCalculator

Problem 1:
I can't get a common type for the worth calculators (to use it in a class that returns proper calculators for given asset ID). So trying to do the following raises a compiler error (because IAssetId is a more base type than Currency in MoneyWorthCalculator):
IAssetWorthCalculator<IAssetId> worthCalculator = new MoneyWorthCalculator();

Problem 2:
Each calculator has a CalculateWorth method, that accepts only a specific parameter type, so MoneyWorthCalculator won't accept IAssetId.
I was thinking about using a non-generic versions of the worth calculators, but that would require method parameter type checking, which would break the Liskov Substitution Principle:
public class MoneyWorthCalculator : IAssetWorthCalculator
{
    public decimal CalculateWorth(IAssetId assetId)
    {
        if (assetId is not Currency)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        return 10;
    }
}


What's wrong with just checking the type in the foreach loop and calculate the worth separately? You are not limited to just one variable of type IAssetWorthCalculator<IAssetId>. Create a MoneyWorthCalculator and a EtfWorthCalculator, check id is ..., and use the correct calculator.

it's very unclear how would you make the calculations for assert worth based on the string tbh...maybe a fuller example?

Without making changes to the defined abstractions, you can change the TotalWorthCalculator to the following:
public class TotalWorthCalculator
{
    private readonly IList<object> calculators;

    public TotalWorthCalculator(IList<object> calculators)
    {
        this.calculators = calculators;
    }

    public decimal GetTotalWorth(IList<IAssetId> assetIds) =>
        assetId.Select(this.Calculate).Sum();
    
    private double Calculate(IAssetId id)
    {
        Type calculatorType =
            typeof(IAssetWorthCalculator<>).MakeGenericType(id.GetType());
    
        dynamic calculator = this.calculators
            .Single(c => calculatorType.IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType());
            
        return calculator.CalculateWorth((dynamic)id);
    }
}

This solution uses Reflection and dynamic typing. You can instantiate the TotalWorthCalculator as follows:
var calculator = new TotalWorthCalculator(new List<object>()
{
    new MoneyWorthCalculator(),
    new EtfWorthCalculator()
});

Things to consider:

Instead of solely having a generic IAssetWorthCalculator<T> interface, you might let it inherit from a non-generic IAssetWorthCalculator interface. Although this makes the implementations slightly more complicated, it prevents the use of dynamic typing. It also allows you to inject the more pleasant IListinto theTotalWorthCalculator's constructor, compared to the more obscure IList. This will also simplify composing the TotalWorthCalculatorusing a DI Container, as they will have trouble resolving anIList` for you as the type isn't specific.
Dynamic typing is simply a form of Reflection, so please be aware that the code will keep compiling, but will start failing at runtime when you change the signature of the IAssetWorthCalculator<T>.CalculateWorth method. Also note that calling .CalculateWorth using dynamic will fail on any type that isn't defined with the public keyword. I consider this a bug in the C# compiler's runtime code, but is probably a security feature. If you stick with using dynamic typing, make sure to add some unit tests to your project testing the correctness of the TotalWorthCalculator.
Another option to get rid of the dynamic typing, while the non-generic IAssetWorthCalculator isn't suitable, is to use a generic adapter that wraps a generic IAssetWorthCalculator<T> while implementing a non-generic interface, e.g. ICalculationAdapter { double Calculate(IAssetId id); }. This will still require some reflection to create new CalculationAdapter<T> instances, but at least makes the solution safe from Refactoring.
In case you stick with the use of


"using dynamic will fail on any type that isn't defined with the public keyword" - Why is that? (dynamic works with anonymous-types, for example, and those are all internal)

@Dai: Yes, anonymous types generated by the C# compiler are defined as internal, but they exhibit the exact same problem. The problem, however, only appears when you are using dynamic on an internal type that is not local to the assembly that the dynamic code runs on. You can test this yourself: return an anonymous type from a method defined in library A and consume that type in library B and use dynamic it. It will fail with a message similar to "'object' does not contain a definition for '...'".

Well, if you are using contravariance with in keyword, you are effectively saying that no subclass is allowed for the IAssetWorthCalculator.
So even if you could have a way to do what you after, you would get errors eventually.
This code would not complie:
AssetWorthCalculator<IAssetId> generic = null;
AssetWorthCalculator<Currency> lessGeneric = null;

generic = lessGeneric;

with error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'console.AssetWorthCalculator<console.Currency>' to 'console.AssetWorthCalculator<console.IAssetId>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

while lessGeneric = generic would be perfectly fine.
So you need to rethink your design.
What you want is covariance, but you are using type parameter for arguemnt, for which contravariance is required.

I think you need an interface type for the the List<T> such as:
public interface IAmAnAssetAndIKnowMyWorth {
    decimal CalculateWorth();
}

and a generic class that implements it:
public class GenericKnowsItsWorth<TAssetId>(
TAssetId assetId, ICalculator<TAssetId> calculator) :
IAmAnAssetAndIKnowMyWorth
where TAssetId : IAssetId {
    public decimal CalculateWorth() => calculator.CalculateWorth(assetId);
}

in which you can inject different calculators that implement
public interface ICalculator<T> where T : IAssetId {
    public decimal CalculateWorth(T assetId);
}

for T being Currency such as
public class MoneyWorthCalculator : ICalculator<Currency> {
    public decimal CalculateWorth(Currency assetId) {
       return default;
    }
}

we can constructs instances like this:
IAmAnAssetAndIKnowMyWorth currencyKnowsItsWorth = new GenericKnowsItsWorth<Currency>(
new Currency("EUR"), 
    new MoneyWorthCalculator());

this will make things easy at the end:
public decimal GetTotalWorth(IList<IAmAnAssetAndIKnowMyWorth assets)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    foreach (IAmAnAssetAndIKnowMyWorth asset in assets)
    {
        sum += asset.CalculateWorth();
    }

    return sum;
}

This will lead to a bit more work in constructing the IList<IAmAnAssetAndIKnowMyWorth> with pairing of the AssetIds and the Calculators but that shouldn't be too much trouble imo.

I think you have to read about Factory Pattern, It will help you to substitute the class based on the currency and asset

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
